# We are seeing constant crashing with QField Android

Tags: qfield

When adding pictures to the project or drawing polygons the app just crashes.
I am running version 3.0.6

Everything in the past worked seamlessly.
Anyone else seeing this, and is there a fix under way?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a link to the upstream issue https://github.com/opengisch/QField/issues/4704